# Get random list item android

Tags: android

I want to get a random list item from a list on click of button in android. Can someone guide me to a tutorial or example where I can find how this can be done, or if someone has already done something like this can i see a sample code. I'm clueless as how to get by it. Need help.

```
public class RandomActivity extends Activity {
String arr[]={"A","B","C","D","E"};
```

ListView list;
    p v onCreate(Bundle saved) {

```
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>           (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

```
public void onRandom(View v){
    list.getAdapter().getItem(new Random().nextInt(list.getCount()));
    }
```

}
Still not getting the size() method so i substitutedit with getCount().But not generating a random value;

Answer (score 8):

Use the `Random` class (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html)

```
list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()))
```

Comment: Why get a double?
`list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size())` will get a random element without casting or floating point numbers.

Comment: @tom: I am using your method but it is giving me a size() undefined error for list.size() method. What do i do?

Comment: @Shashwat are you trying to get the item from a List or a ListView?

Comment: a listview. Should i get it from a list?

Comment: Then do `listView.getAdapter().getItem(new Random...)` instead

Comment: @tom: i've posted what i am doing but it still is not giving the size() method, so i substituted it with getCount(). But nothing is generating. I'm randomizing the list on a button click.

Answer (score 1):

### Since Kotlin 1.3:

```
list.random()
```

If the list is empty, it will throw `NoSuchElementException`. [Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/random.html)

If you can't use Kotlin, then [@tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703904/7855861) is your way to go.